# swift: add UITableView to .xib view

Tags: uitableview, dynamic, uiview, xib

I can't add a dynamic `UITableView` to a `.xib` View. How can I solve this?

The content field, where you can select dynamic content cells, does not appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tableView should have the content set to Dynamic Prototypes in the xib file.

[image: TableView dynamic prototype]

If your already have this, just give some more details about your problem.

Hope this helps though!

### Update

It seems like you can't really change the content in a tableView that is defined in a `xib` file. I think the only option you have if to create `xib` files for your cells separately and then use them in your datasource methods.

I suppose the reason for this is that you need to register the custom cell classes for the various cell identifiers.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't have that... This is what I have: http://i58.tinypic.com/rr5un9.png And the UITableView looks like this: http://i59.tinypic.com/ou71wo.png